# Missing required dependencies ['numpy'] in AWS Lambda function

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, numpy, aws-lambda

I guess many people have come across the same issue. I have tried to find every possible blog and try every method. I have reached this point and stuck here.

I am using Serverless framework and virtualenv.

serverless.yml:

```
 service: test-pandas
 provider:
   name: aws
   runtime: python2.7
 plugins:
   - serverless-python-requirements
 package:
    exclude:
       - venv/**
       - node_modules/**
 functions:
    hello:
       handler: validation.hello
```

validation.py:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

def hello(event, context):
    return "hello world"
```

I am using python 2.7. I have run these commands in Virtualenv:

```
virtualenv venv --python=python2
source venv/bin/activate
pip install pandas
pip freeze > requirements.txt
cat requirements.txt
```

Before creating the requirements.txt, the error was "No import module named pandas" and after I setup serverless-python-requirements, I am getting "Missing required dependencies ['numpy']".

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Did you install `numpy`? surprised pandas didn't install it as a dependency, but ...

Comment: Yes Pandas did install Numpy by default. I can see both packages. Hence confused about the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used Docker to package and deploy the Lambda function with the libraries.

Add the following in serverless.yml:

```
custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: non-linux
```

Make sure Docker is running on your machine and deploy it using serverless commands. Another thing I noticed is that, after using Docker, the .zip filesize reduced almost half of the original filesize.

Comment: if you already tried building without this solution, make sure serverless does not reuse the cache of the requirements file when deploying. if you see something like 
`Serverless: Using static cache of requirements found at /Users/vincent/Library/Caches/serverless-python-requirements/2cf433de4980cbe5f2b691456cb28222399a8f03ff9352ad0a6e771186108712_slspyc ...`

remove the cache folder and deploy again.